# How to get image from video file

Tags: android, image

Hi i'm developer in korea. I have some question so i enter this site.

```
    InputStream is;
    URL url = 
         new URL("http://112.216.25.58:8888/VOD_LAUNCHER/media/youtube_sample3.mp4");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url.toURI().toString());
    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url.toString());
    //MediaMetadataRetriever ret = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    //ret.setDataSource(url.toString());
    //Bitmap bitmap = ret.getFrameAtTime(0);
    //mImageView.setImageURI(uri);

    //Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri.toString(), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

private Bitmap getPreview(URI uri) {
        File image = new File(uri);

    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1))
        return null;

    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
            : bounds.outWidth;

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), opts);     
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), 
                                              contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

I try to use ThumbnailUtil and etc but it didn't work.
How to get ThumbnailImage on android 4.0? 
Thanks any reply.

Comment: it didn't work does not describe a problem, what specifically happens when it 'doesn't work' ?

Comment: cursor was null and thumbnail image didn't appear on project.

Answer (score 20):

From API level 8 you can just do this:

```
String path = /*get video path*/;
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Nice and simple :)

Comment: Its an astonishing answer.

Comment: But Dose Not Work In Android 4 And Above !

Answer (score 8):

If you want to extract a frame of a video you should use [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html). The code should be something like that:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever media = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
media.setDataSource(path);
Bitmap extractedImage = media.getFrameAtTime(time, option);
```

Hope it´s useful

Comment: setDataSource is not for uri

Comment: What do you mean?? You can pass an uri or a path (read the documentation)

Comment: This works for api 31

Answer (score 1):

Try This to get Thumbnail of a Video.

```
ImageView videoview;
 Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("YOUR VIDEO STRING PATH",   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 Bitmap bmThumbnail = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumb, 0, 0,
 thumb.getWidth(), thumb.getHeight(), matrix, true);
 videoview.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

Edited: Use this method to get string path of Video URI.

```
/**
     * Try to return the absolute file path of the Gallery video.
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return the file path or null
     */
    public static String getVideoPathFromGallary(final Context context,Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {  MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};
        Cursor cursor = ((Activity) context).managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null)
            return null;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        int fileSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
        long duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION)));
        System.out.println("size: " + fileSize);
        System.out.println("duration: " + duration);
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("YOUR VIDEO STRING PATH",   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND); return null so it did't work

Comment: use getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) this method to convert your Video Uri to string and use that in place of "YOUR VIDEO STRING PATH".

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(getRealPathFromURI(Uri.parse("http://112.216.25.58:8888/VOD_LAUNCHER/media/youtube_sample3.mp4")), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

Comment: Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground(); cursor is null, it didn't work

Comment: getVideoPathFromGallary Cursor cursor = ((Activity)context).managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null); cursor is null

Answer (score 1):

very simple !!! you can use glide library.

first add an imageView on videoView and use the code below:

>

```
 GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).load("empty")
    .thumbnail(GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).load("videoURL"))
    .into(imageView);
```

this code will download an image, and eventually, that leads to less internet consumption.