# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at Home.java:35

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fatal-error, forceclose

I'm getting an error stating `FATAL EXCEPTION: main Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at Home.java:35` when attempting to create a thumbnail from a MP4 using the following example: [How to get image from video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374959/how-to-get-image-from-video-file)

Line 35 is `thumb.getWidth(), thumb.getHeight(), matrix, true);`

The MP4 URL is valid - so I'm not sure exactly why this is happening.

### Source:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);


        ImageView videoview;
        videoview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
         Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
         Bitmap bmThumbnail = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumb, 0, 0,
         thumb.getWidth(), thumb.getHeight(), matrix, true);
         videoview.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);



    }
}
```

Comment: from your code viewView can only be null, as suggested by eclise and illustrated by the exception. now, you know where the crash is, you know why, and you know which variable is the issue. what is your question ?

Comment: Source updated - I think it should be a valid question now.

Comment: I don't understand...the edit didn't add anything, it just fixed the formatting and removed relevant information. (Note: I didn't vote to close as a dupe, I voted to close as "insufficient information to diagnose the problem")

Answer (score 4):

You didn't initialize `videoview`.

You can do that like this:

```
videoview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView)
```

Comment: Does this look correct? I tried it and it's still force closing:

http://pastebin.com/EFUaSD2f

Comment: Is your `ImageView`
's Id really `myImageView`?

Comment: Yes: <ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YdbMrHiu

Comment: You've still got this line `ImageView videoview = null;` in there.

Comment: I removed it - still crashing on the same line:

http://pastebin.com/duNtG0W3

Comment: thumb.getWidth(), thumb.getHeight(), matrix, true);

Comment: Any ideas? I'm stumped...

Comment: Hmm what are you trying to do with the bitmap? The bitmap creation is throwing an exception.

Comment: I'm trying to create a thumbnail from a video 

P.S.

when debugging thumb is  null for some reason - any idea why?

Comment: `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()` takes a file path to a video on the device's storage as a parameter. You are passing in a URL to a video.

Comment: Any idea what I could/should do instead? (I need them stored online)

Comment: I would create a thumbnail on the server side and fetch the image on the client side(in your android app)

Comment: Sadly - that is not an option for this project.

Comment: Hmm sorry I don't think that's possible then (afaik), you would have to download the video and then create create a thumbnail. There might be another way to do that, but I'm not sure.